# JAXB and inheritance works when marshaling; but not unmarshaling

Tags: java, inheritance, jaxb

I want to marshal / unmarshal  objects of a class that inherits form another one.

I start with the class `Thing`:

```java
import java.util.List;

public class Thing {
  private List<String> strings;

  public List<String> getStrings() {
    return strings;
  }

  public void setStrings(List<String> strings) {
    this.strings = strings;
  }
}
```

I extend this class and annotate it with JAXB-annotations.

```java
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class JaxbThing extends Thing {

  // @XmlElementWrapper(name = "list")
  @XmlElementWrapper(name = "strings")
  @XmlElement(name = "string")
  public List<String> getStrings() {
    return super.getStrings();
  }

  public void setStrings(List<String> string) {
    super.setStrings(string);
  }
}
```

Then I run the following marshalling/unmarshalling program:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JaxbThing t = new JaxbThing();
    t.setStrings(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
    try {
      File f = new File("jaxb-file.xml");

      JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(JaxbThing.class);

      Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
      m.marshal(t, f);

      Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
      JaxbThing t2 = (JaxbThing) um.unmarshal(f);

      System.out.println(t2.getStrings());  // I expect to see [a, b, c]

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

The content of the XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxbThing>
    <strings>
        <string>a</string>
        <string>b</string>
        <string>c</string>
    </strings>
</jaxbThing>
```

Everything seems to be correct. But the result of the unmarshaling is surprising to me, because the console shows:

```
[
    ]
```

When I expected to see `[a, b, c]`

If I annotate the `strings` property in this way:

```java
  @XmlElementWrapper(name = "list")
  // @XmlElementWrapper(name = "strings")
  @XmlElement(name = "string")
  public List<String> getStrings() {
    return super.getStrings();
  }
```

Then the console shows the expected `[a, b, c]`.

I guess that JAXB unmarshaler is using class `Thing` instead of `JaxbThing` to unmarshal the XML file content. In fact if I annotate the class `Thing` with `@XmlTransient` I get the expected result.

However I do not understand this behavior of JAXB.

Can anyone explain me it, please? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems is that you are overriding a property from the parent class.  JAXB thinks `JAXBThing` has"

1. A property called `strings` (inherited from `String`) mapped to the element `strings`.
2. A property called `strings` (defined on `JAXBThing` mapped to the element `string` under the element `strings`.

If you put a break point in `setStrings` method on `JAXBThing` you will see that it is first called with the correct data, and then it is called a second time with incorrect data that overrides the initial set (because it thinks they are different properties that share a setter).

You can always remove the `Thing` class by annotating it with `@XmlTransient`.

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

@XmlTransient
public class Thing {
  private List<String> strings;

  public List<String> getStrings() {
    return strings;
  }

  public void setStrings(List<String> strings) {
      System.out.println("Thing" + strings);
    this.strings = strings;
  }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/ignoring-inheritance-with-xmltransient.html

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answer. I have done what you suggest me. You are right, `setStrings` method is called twice. But, at least in my experiment, it is never called with the correct values.

Bellow I provide the modified sample code. I added a few lines to trace execution. I have also activated the marshaller formatted output, in order to better see what happens in the process of unmarshalling.

The base class `Thing`

```java
import java.util.List;

public class Thing {
  private List<String> strings;

  public List<String> getStrings() {
    return strings;
  }

  public void setStrings(List<String> strings) {
    /*new*/ System.out.printf("Thing.setStrings called. Prev. this.strings: %s (size %s). Received strings param: %s", this.strings, (this.strings!=null ? this.strings.size():"null"),strings);
    this.strings = strings;
    /*new*/ System.out.printf(". New this.strings: %s (size %s).%n%n", this.strings, (this.strings!=null ? this.strings.size():"null"));
  }
}
```

The extended class `JaxbThing`

```java
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class JaxbThing extends Thing {

  // @XmlElementWrapper(name = "list")
  @XmlElementWrapper(name = "strings")
  @XmlElement(name = "string")
  public List<String> getStrings() {
    return super.getStrings();
  }

  public void setStrings(List<String> string) {
    /*new*/ System.out.printf("JaxbThing.setStrings called. Received strings param: %s (size %s)%n",string,(string !=null?string.size():"null"));
    super.setStrings(string);
  }
}
```

The test program:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {    
    System.out.println("---- Initiallizing");
    JaxbThing t = new JaxbThing();
    t.setStrings(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
    try {
      File f = new File("jaxb-file.xml");

      JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(JaxbThing.class);

      System.out.println("---- Marshalling");
      Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
      m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);   /*new*/
      m.marshal(t, f);

      System.out.println("---- UnMarshalling");
      Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
      JaxbThing t2 = (JaxbThing) um.unmarshal(f);

      System.out.println("---- Showing results");
      System.out.println(t2.getStrings());  // I expect to see [a, b, c]

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

The results are as follows (I have numbered the lines):

```
1  ---- Initiallizing
2  JaxbThing.setStrings called. Received strings param: [a, b, c] (size 3)
3  Thing.setStrings called. Prev. this.strings: null (size null). Received strings param: [a, b, c]. New this.strings: [a, b, c] (size 3).
4  
5  ---- Marshalling
6  ---- UnMarshalling
7  JaxbThing.setStrings called. Received strings param: [] (size 0)
8  Thing.setStrings called. Prev. this.strings: null (size null). Received strings param: []. New this.strings: [] (size 0).
9  
10 JaxbThing.setStrings called. Received strings param: [
       ] (size 1)
11 Thing.setStrings called. Prev. this.strings: [
       ] (size 1). Received strings param: [
       ]. New this.strings: [
       ] (size 1).
12 
13 ---- Showing results
14 [
         ]
```

During unmarshalling, a new `JaxbThing` is built, its `JaxbThing.setStrings` is first called with a 0-length list of strings (line 7). Consequently, the `Thing.setStrings` is called (line 8). The previous value of the object's strings field (`this.strings`) was null. Then, the `JaxbThing.setStrings` is called again (line 10), but now with a list of strings that contains an string with a '\n' character plus 4 blank spaces (I guess this corresponds to the indenting of the XML file). Two remarks:

1. The `JaxbThing.setStrings` is never called with the correct values (unless I haven’t seen it).
2. The second call to `JaxbThing.setStrings` (line 10) causes the second call to `Thing.setStrings` (line 11). But now the previous value of `this.strings` is not the 0-length list of strings set in the previous call to `Thing.setStrings` in line 8. It is already the '\n' character plus 4 blank spaces that is passed as parameter.

Any clue explaining this behavior?

Comment: I will need to go back and take another look.  The important point to take away is that JAXB doesn't allow you to override a mapped property.  You will need to either mark the parent class or property transient to get the behaviour you are looking for.